# how to create javascript for work pie chart in php codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

controller (connect the model and view )

```
function viewdashboard(){
  $this->load->model('AgentPerformance/agentPerformance_model');
  $this->agentPerformance_model->dashboard(); 
}
```

model get data in database.

```
function dashboard(){
 $this->db->select("count(`idCall`) as answerCount",False)
     ->from("call")
     ->where("idEmployee",20)
     ->where("C_date",date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime(2015-04-22)))
     ->where("C_ansornot",'Not Answer')
        ->get()->result_array();
  $this->db->select("count(`idCall`) as answerCount",False)
     ->from("call")
     ->where("idEmployee",20)
     ->where("C_date",date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime(2015-04-22)))
     ->where("C_ansornot",'Rejected')
     ->get()->result_array();
  } 
}
```

HTML (view )

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; 
max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div> )

Comment: You need suggestions regarding how to create javascript pie chart  ?

Comment: Check this link maybe it will help you [js charts.com](http://www.jscharts.com/how-to-use-pie-charts)

Comment: sir, i want to know how to get database data in to json

Answer (score 0):

> in your controller assign the value returned by the model to a variable and return it as json using json encode function

```
function viewdashboard(){
  $this->load->model('AgentPerformance/agentPerformance_model');
  $result = $this->agentPerformance_model->dashboard(); 
  $val = json_encode($result);
  return $val;
    }
```

now you can get this value as json in your javascript.You can also use

> echo $val instead of return $val

Hope it helped...

Comment: thank for your idea.... but now i have another question.  how to display json encode value in javascript. and  how to pass that data to pie chart.

Comment: @amaya you can get the json values which are returned from the controller in your ajax success function. You can catch it using any variable name.
success: function (data) in which data is the variable which has the json value returned

Comment: @amaya and for implementing the chart you can refer this link [jscharts.com](http://www.jscharts.com/)